# Does my HTC Wildfire S data cable work with a Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have a HTC Wildfire S and I was wondering if it works on a Samsung Galaxy S2. Sorry if I posted this in the wrong forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wildfire S uses a [microUSB cable](http://www.htcaccessorystore.com/uk/p_htc_item.aspx?i=209295&phone=209273), same as the Galaxy SII, it should work fine

Comment: Just to add more info. MicroUSB is used by the vast majority of smartphones. It's just not used by Apple devices and tablets.